# ./configure unable to find header files

Tags: macos, sdl, ogg, vorbis, sdl-mixer

I'm compiling a project that uses SDL_mixer to play `.ogg` files. However, `Mix_Init(MIX_INIT_OGG)` fails, and `Mix_GetError()` returns `"Mixer not built with Ogg Vorbis support"`. The version of SDL_mixer I'm using is 1.2.12, downloaded via Homebrew.

So I downloaded the sources for SDL_mixer (same version, 1.2.12), and tried building it with Ogg support, i.e. `./configure --enable-music-ogg`, but `configure` is unable to find the Vorbis header files. This is the output it's giving:

```
checking vorbis/vorbisfile.h usability... no
checking vorbis/vorbisfile.h presence... no
checking for vorbis/vorbisfile.h... no
checking for ov_open_callbacks in -lvorbisfile... no
configure: WARNING: *** Unable to find Ogg Vorbis library (http://www.xiph.org/)
configure: WARNING: Ogg Vorbis support disabled
```

I even tried passing `--includedir=/usr/local/include` to `configure`, without success. I have both the Vorbis and Ogg header files in `/usr/local/include`, so e.g. the path to `vorbisfile.h` is `/usr/local/include/vorbis/vorbisfile.h`. I also tried building both libogg and libvorbis from scratch, but I still get the same errors. I'm using OS X 10.11.1 beta.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit**

Output of `brew ls sdl_mixer`:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/sdl_mixer/1.2.12/include/SDL/SDL_mixer.h
/usr/local/Cellar/sdl_mixer/1.2.12/lib/libSDL_mixer-1.2.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/sdl_mixer/1.2.12/lib/pkgconfig/SDL_mixer.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/sdl_mixer/1.2.12/lib/ (2 other files)
```

Comment: Not sure what command you used to install `SDL_mixer`, let's say it was `brew install sdl_mixer`, that being the case, you could try `brew options sdl_mixer` to see if there is an *"ogg option"*.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did it with `brew install sdl_mixer` yes. I just checked and there is a `--with-libvorbis` option, but it doesn't seem to work for some reason, SDL still says that "Mixer not built with Ogg Vorbis support".

Comment: So, I presume you have now done `brew install sdl_mixer --with-libvorbis`? If you then do `brew ls sdl_mixer` it should show you what it has installed and where.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes that's what I did. Edited the output of `brew ls` into the question.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  The libraries are all installed, but building SDL_mixer from source does not work.  I also tried building ogg and vorbis from source.  No joy.

Answer (score 1):

You can run now

```
brew install sdl2_mixer --with-libvorbis
```

Comment: That's what I ran (except `sdl_mixer`, not `sdl2_mixer`), but it didn't help.

Comment: Oh sorry this must be exclusive to the sdl2_mixer formulae